# How does Grails convert camelCase to a more human-friendly title to display to users?

Tags: grails, groovy

When I create a Groovy on Grails application with Mongo DB, in the index view there is an `<f:table>` tag which on default displays all documents within the Mongo collection. In the UI I see that the keys coming from the database, e.g. `userName` are on default turned into a title "User Name" in the displayed table.

This seems to be done inside the tag `<f:table>`. I can't see though how Grails is turning these camel case keys into a human-readable title.

I would like to do the same in the views that I am generating which don't use the `<f:table>` tag. Is there a proper method for this or a Grails tag that I should use specifically for the `camelcase` keys?

Comment: You can call `GrailsNameUtils.getNaturalName("someName")` https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/77843bd857d3718d439e264b013eb566fc3afd32/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/grails/util/GrailsNameUtils.java#L383

Answer (score 1):

The tests at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/e2202939d6d5e8616dd5e16f1ce21f692cdd0061/grails-bootstrap/src/test/groovy/grails/util/GrailsNameUtilsTests.groovy demonstrate how to do this.

For example:

```
assertEquals("First Name", GrailsNameUtils.getNaturalName("firstName"))
```